# Templating values for a bash script for apache conf files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I'm trying to automate creating vhosts on my computer. This is merely a learning experience for bash scripting. I'm currently novice. I'm trying to learn more about awk, sed.

Anyways, this is my conf file. What would be the most efficient way to find and replace from command line? I'll eventually replace some forms with tokens, like {DOMAIN} and {PATH}

```
NameVirtualHost commerce.l:*

<Directory "/home/chris/workspace/dev.commerce/html">
        Options Indexes Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost commerce.l>
    DocumentRoot /home/chris/workspace/dev.commerce/html
    ServerName commerce.l
    ErrorLog logs/commerce.error
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <Directory "/home/chris/workspace/dev.commerce/html">
            RewriteEngine on
            # needed by Drupal 7 for "clean URLs"
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

P.S. I'm on Ubuntu 11.04 natty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for a [here-document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document): include the template in your script, and use `$variable_name` when you want to substitute variables, or `$(shell-command)` to substitute the output of any shell command.

The here-document begins on the line after the marker `<<EOF` (you can replace `EOF` by any word) and ends on a line containing exactly `EOF` (no indentation allowed). Inside the template, the same characters are special as inside double quotes: `` "$`\ `` (note the backquote, which needs to be protected `` \` ``).

```
DOMAIN=commerce.l
PATH=/home/chris/workspace/dev.commerce/html
cat >>/etc/apache/sites-available/$DOMAIN
NameVirtualHost $DOMAIN:*

<Directory "$PATH">
…
</VirtualHost>
EOF
```

Comment: Do you know of any other web resources relating to this? I'm trying to find some good examples.

Comment: @Chris Read the Wikipedia article and your shell's manual and your favorite shell book. Google for “here document” or “heredoc”.